# Enable android's phone speaker in program

Tags: android

I wrote an app that handles incoming calls and answers them automatically. I want to set voice to phone's loud speaker and it works fine on android up to 4 but not 4.1 and 4.2.

Code:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

I have required permission in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

I am getting a silent exception in my LogCat that says that I have not `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` permission but I have defined this in manifest:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10046 nor current process has android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE.
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.silenceRinger(ITelephony.java:577)
at net.farayan.android.driveranswer.AutoAnswerIntentService.answerPhoneAidl(AutoAnswerIntentService.java:155)
at net.farayan.android.driveranswer.AutoAnswerIntentService.onHandleIntent(AutoAnswerIntentService.java:92)
at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Comment: The exception doesn't appear to be related to enabling the speaker, but to muting the ringtone when answering the call (which the phone's audio HAL implementation should handle by itself). Anyway, `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` is not granted to normal applications, regardless of whether you've added it in your manifest or not. If it worked on a device running Android 4.0 it sounds like a bug to me (unless you were running some custom Android version).

Answer (score 1):

As [per docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS), `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` permission is not for you:

> Allows modification of the telephony state - power on, mmi, etc. Does
>   not include placing calls.
>
> **Not for use by third-party applications.**

it used to work on pre 2.3, but it was changed starting at v.2.3 and since that version permission is granted only to system apps, which means either pre-installed into a system folder on the ROM or signed with manufacturer using their security certificate.

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Add above to your manifest file